# Как изменить цвет элементов TreeViewItem на соответствующий цвет из Node?

Tags: c#, wpf, color, treeview

Цвет всех элементов дерева должен браться из *Node* `x_color`

Здесь цвет определяется триггерами, а нужно задать из *Node* дерева

**XAML**

```
<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree_b">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Silver"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" >
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding collection_node}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                        
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}">                                            
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**Node**

```
public class Node
{
    public string name_ { get; set; }

    public Color x_color { get; set; }

    //
    public ObservableCollection<Node> collection_node { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить привязку к `x_color` в `ItemContainerStyle`. Проблема только в том, что свойство `Foreground` принимает тип Brush, а не Color. Есть два варианта: изменить в Node тип свойства x_color или использовать `ValueConverter`.

**Вариант 1:**

.cs

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        collection_node = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }

    public string name_ { get; set; }
    public Brush x_color { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> collection_node { get; set; }
}
```

.xaml

```
<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree_b">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding x_color}" />
       </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding collection_node}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}">
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

**Вариант 2:**

.cs

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        collection_node = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }

    public string name_ { get; set; }
    public Color x_color { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> collection_node { get; set; }
}

public class ColorToBrushConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = (Color) value;
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var brush = (SolidColorBrush) value;
        return brush.Color;
    }
}
```

.xaml

```
<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree_b">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <my:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="conv"/>
    </TreeView.Resources>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding x_color, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding collection_node}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}">
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```